# Step by step Red Hat Update for OpenSSL

Tags: linux, rhel, security, openssl, vulnerability

How to update

1. Red Hat Update for Open Secure Sockets Layer (OpenSSL) (RHSA-2022:1066)
2. Red Hat Update for java-11-openjdk security (RHSA-2022:1440)

Please guide me step by step, because I have no experience about this

I Use MobaXterm to access Linux.

Linux Version:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.9 (Maipo)"
```

Comment: I would suggest you use RedHat support for this. If you don't have a support contract with RedHat then you will need one to access their update repositories anyway

Answer (score 1):

Update instructions are provided in each advisory, for example in [RHSA-2022:1066](https://access.redhat.com/errata/RHSA-2022:1066) and [the maintenance instructions linked there](https://access.redhat.com/articles/11258).

The short answer for RHEL 7, assuming the system is correctly registered, is to run

```
yum update
```

as root. This will apply all available updates. If that’s not appropriate, you can specify packages to update as arguments to `yum update`; each advisory lists all the affected packages for each affected product.